# jQuery JSON parsing fails for data attribute with double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am experiencing that HTML encoded values are not correctly fetched where jQuery reads the attribute value—the quotes are decoded—so the JSON parsing fails with this value.

Is this a bug in jQuery or am I not encoding my values correctly?

Here's my HTML encoded JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "organisation_id": "1",
        "badge_id": "49",
        "target": "15",
        "target_type": "actions",
        "target_title": null,
        "target_description": null,
        "start": "2014-01-15",
        "name": "Our goal",
        "description": "Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. &quot;Nullam&quot; id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.",
        "created": "2013-08-07 14:26:56"
    },
    {
        "id": "19",
        "organisation_id": "1",
        "badge_id": "49",
        "target": "30000000",
        "target_type": "numeric",
        "target_title": "Revenue contribution",
        "target_description": "Specify how much this action contributes to the revenue goal",
        "start": "2014-01-21",
        "name": "November revenue",
        "description": "Reach revenue of $30,000,000 in November. Let&#039;s do this.",
        "created": "2014-01-21 16:59:25"
    }
]
```

Note the `&quot;` in the `description` property.

And here's a reproduction of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/J8Xv6/

I think this is an issue which is appearing in newer versions of jQuery. Just updated from 1.7.x to 1.11.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's invalid JSON.  By the time the string makes it to JavaScript, that HTML entity will have become a double-quote character. Double-quote characters in strings must be escaped with a backslash.

The HTML-encoding of the character makes the HTML parser happy, but it results in an attribute value that's got a plain double-quote character in the middle of the JSON value (string constant).

If you put a backslash before the HTML entity, it'll be valid JSON.

*edit* — in your jsfiddle, you're attempting to fetch the data attribute with the jQuery `.data()` method.  That's fine, but be aware that when jQuery sees stuff that *looks like* JSON, it will try to parse it for you. Thus when you get back the attribute value it'll already be parsed.

Comment: He knows that, that's the entire problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a reference for your point?

Comment: @RonniEgeriis a reference?  Well, [there's the JSON language spec](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: @Cerbrus right, and the solution is to make the attribute value not be an invalid JSON expression ...

Comment: @Pointy I know of the spec, but for reference it's always appropriate to point in the direction of the part of the spec where the point you're putting out there is described.

Comment: @RonniEgeriis it's the grammar for string constants. Note where it says, "**Any UNICODE character except " or \ or control character**".

Comment: For reference, I am using PHP's json_encode function. Why it doesn't encode correctly is really odd to me, but there are some optional flags which can ensure that special chars are converted to unicode notation: `JSON_HEX_QUOT`, `JSON_HEX_TAG`, `JSON_HEX_AMP`, `JSON_HEX_APOS` http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: If the HTML `&quot;` entities are in the string *before* you call the PHP "json_encode" function, it almost certainly will not know to add the backslash; I don't know *any* JSON encoder that would do that.

Comment: @Pointy Absolutely. The HTML encoding was something I added, because I thought that was the solution. It removed the HTML parsing error that would occur with single quotes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46776/discussion-between-ronni-egeriis-and-pointy)

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute taking the data this way,

```
"[{"id":"1","organisation_id":"1","badge_id":"49","target":"15","target_type":"actions","target_title":null,"target_description":null,"start":"2014-01-15","name":"Our goal","description":"Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. "Nullam" id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.","created":"2013-08-07 14:26:56"},{"id":"19","organisation_id":"1","badge_id":"49","target":"30000000","target_type":"numeric","target_title":"Revenue contribution","target_description":"Specify how much this action contributes to the revenue goal","start":"2014-01-21","name":"November revenue","description":"Reach revenue of $30,000,000 in November. Let's do this.","created":"2014-01-21 16:59:25"}]"
```

The error will be raises bold word , double quotes contains inside double quotes.

`"`Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. **"Nullam"** id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`"`